# What do you think about "TCPDF like" PHP solutions to generate a PDF?

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, wkhtmltopdf

Don't you think the TCPDF solution force you to reivent the wheel, in term of layout rendering?

I think TCPDF doesn't allow a good separation of concerns, and is just too limited when you try to render dynamic tables, or wide portions of text.

I'm pretty interested in alternative solutions like [wkhtml2pdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) or [XSL-FOP](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/), but I would like some experience feedback.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Jakub That's [no longer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183) how community wiki works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used FOP and Jasper Reports over the last years. Both are Java-Solutions but can be easily used within a PHP application. For that I use a PHP/Java-Bridge (at the moment the one from the ZendServer CE, but there is also a Open-Source-Bridge at Sourceforge)

For me JasperReports works better. There is a graphical WYSIWYG-Editor (iReport) for creating the Templates. FOP is great too but writing the XSL by hand is difficult and lengtly.

Comment: Thanks! in the same idea, there is OpenOfficeServer + odt templates.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried the two pdf generators that you mentioned, i'll give them a shoot...
I used TCPDF and it worked good for me... It allows easily to turn html code to a pdf file...
The drawbacks is that the translation is not always perfect, specially when you use css styles.
Another drawback could be the heavy weight of the library...

Comment: Yes, as you said, css styles are not very well handled. There is DOMPDF which handle more css rules than TCPDF.